# Sessions and user_id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, userid

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding sessions and authentication with Rails. So basically, I tried to set a session based on user_id, following a tutorial from a book. Here is the create method in my sessions_controller.rb file:

```
def create
if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  session[:id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Logged in successfully'
else
  flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password combination"
  render :action => 'new'
end
```

end

But, when I try to define a current_user method in my application_controller.rb file, it asks me to reference the session based on user_id:

```
def current_user
  return unless session[:user_id]
  @current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end
```

Here is what confuses me - user_id is an attribute of each Recipe (equivalent of articles or posts in my app) that creates a has_one relationship with a user. nowhere else in my application is user_id defined. so user_id shouldn't be an attribute of a User, right?

Just to clarify, I've listed the parameters for User objects and Recipe objects from the rails console:

```
    2.0.0-p598 :019 >   Recipe 
    => Recipe(id: integer, title: string, body: text, published_at:    
    datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: 
    integer, photo_of_recipe_file_name: string, 
    photo_of_recipe_content_type: string, photo_of_recipe_file_size:   
    integer, photo_of_recipe_updated_at: datetime)

    2.0.0-p598 :020 > User
    => User(id: integer, email: string, hashed_password: string,     
    created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, username: string)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your create method it should be

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

You are setting up a key `:user_id` in the session hash and storing the authenticated user's id `user.id` in it for later use

Key name can be anything

Comment: Thanks that clarifies things